# Proving an expression using Mathematical Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

How can the following expression be proved using mathematical induction?
$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]
{
\cos((n+1)\theta) = 2p_1p_n - p_{n-1}
}
$$
Where
$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]
{
p_1 = \cos\theta, p_0 = 1 , n \geq 1
}
$$

**Edit:** There are actually two equations which are relative to each other the first equation for $n$ is

$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]
{
p_{n+1}= 2p_1p_n - p_{n-1} , n \geq 1
}
$$

The other equation is:
$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]
{
 p_n = \cos(n\theta), n \geq 0
}
$$

We have to use mathematical induction to prove the relation between these two. The $p_n$ can be found using the value from the previous equation for example for $n = 1$ we can use the $p_1 = \cos\theta$ value while when inserting $n = 2$ we use the value of the previous equation.

When I solved the equation I found out that for every $n$ in the 1st equation the value is equalized to $n+1$ of the second equation that is why I wrote $\cos((n+1)\theta)$ in the first place. **For example:**

> For $n=1$ the first equation gives us:
> $$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]
> {
>  p_{1+1} = 2(\cos\theta)^2 - 1
> }
> $$

which is equal to

> $n = 2$ in second equation:

$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]
{
  p_2 = \cos(2\theta)
}
$$

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Please edit your post. It is not readable in it's current state

Comment: What is $p_n$ ?

Comment: As @Digitallis said, please edit the question. Also, can you add what you've tried? It's going to be more helpful to you if you add what you've tried, so someone can hopefully correct the misunderstanding. If you haven't got as far as an attempt - maybe add some ideas you had / what part of it you don't understand? :)

Comment: And yeah also as @MaximilianJanisch - ${p_n}$ is not defined in your post, so you will also have to add this

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Hey sorry for the post I am new to website so didn't know how to edit it. :) I have edited the post hope things are clarified now

Comment: There are still parts of your formulas that are not legible.  Please use the tutorial to which I linked above.  For instance, you would type `$p^n$` to produce $p^n$.

Comment: Use `$p_{n+1}$` to write $p_{n+1}$. Surround mathy object with the dollar signs. Besides making the question comprehensible, we are looking out for what have you tried.

Comment: Please verify that my edits are correct.

Comment: Remember that $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta$. What have you tried?